# CMake bracket escape character for custom target command

Tags: regex, bash, cmake, makefile

I am in need of the bracket escape character used to avoid quoting special characters in CMake when parsing make commands to add_custom_target. This is more of a syntax problem that from my understanding, is not covered in CMake documentation.

An example case is:

```
add_custom_target ( defined_path ALL .exe <args1> | ( ! grep ... )
```

In this example, the extension to `<args1>` is resolved as `| "(" grep ... ")"`. Unfortunately appending backslash before the brackets only works for string cases, i.e. assigning to a variable with set: `set ( something "\(" )`. Even then the variable itself is resolved in the build.make surrounded by quotations. Likewise parsing a pre-formatted list using separate_arguments also resolves with quotations.

The full command without the make formatting is executed successfully.

Comment: Does using `VERBATIM` help? As last resort, you can write full command into file (e.g., using `file(WRITE)`) and execute it in `add_custom_target`.

Comment: Unfortunately VERBATIM doesn't help here (the command was originally written to use it). I should have been more specific in the question, but for multiple reasons an extra file causes complications in my build system and was not considered to be a viable solution for me (even though it will probably save me a lot of grief - CMake grief that is :p !! ).

Comment: I just tested e.g. `add_custom_target( defined_path ALL cat CMakeCache.txt | ( grep 'BINARY' ) )` with CMake 3.2.2 and MSYS. It works fine. So could you please add more details on the environment and versions you are using?

Comment: Thats interesting. I made a typo in the original example and realised the ! operator was missing before grep which may be causing the problem (but I'm doubtful as this is an allowed non-special character in CMake). I'm sure I've tried cat.

As for CMake version, I'm using a variant of CMake 3. I can narrow the minor numbers tomorrow as I don't have access to that particular VM image. Thanks for the response btw :)

Comment: Solved: Didn't realise Cmake required an explicit call to shell in the target command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmake requires an explicit call to shell in the target command